# Clone Select Box Option value in same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, clone, jquery-clone

I have an Address Column in form created in cakephp, where we have Permanent Address and Present Address, in which, address ,country, state, city fields are to be filled. like in below image[image: Address Form]

As seen in picture there is a Select Box **(Same as Above)** which is for cloning the all Address fields (Address, Country, State, City) from Present address to Permanent address for those who have Same Address.
We are only using India's States So we have set country by default India and all india states in state select box, so we have to only call cities option through ajax after state selection by user, as code
//Function for select city

```
 function get_city(UserProfileState)  
    {  
        var state_id=document.getElementById('UserProfileState').value;     
        $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",  
            url: "get_city",  
            data: "UserProfileState="+state_id,  
            success: function(msg){  
                $("#city").html(msg); 
            }  
        });             
    }
```

//Function for Cloning All address fields

```
 $("#chkform").click(function()
        { 
            if($(this).is(":checked")) 
            {
                $("#UserProfilePeraddress").val($("#UserProfilePaddress").val());
                $("#UserProfilePcountry").val($("#UserProfileCountry").val());
                $("#UserProfilePstate").val($("#UserProfileState").val());
                $("#UserProfilePcity").val($("#UserProfileCity").val());
                $("#UserProfilePpincode").val($("#UserProfilePcode").val());
                $("#UserProfilePtelephone").val($("#UserProfileTelephone").val());

            }}
```

As i got value updated from ajax call from page get_city.ctp, but when i clone fields it still does not get value from city field, clone pcity show empty option in select box. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, Updated Clone Function as

```
if($(this).is(":checked")) 
        {
            $("#UserProfilePeraddress").val($("#UserProfilePaddress").val());
            $("#UserProfilePcountry").val($("#UserProfileCountry").val());
            $("#UserProfilePstate").val($("#UserProfileState").val());               
            var state_id=document.getElementById('UserProfileState').value;
            var city_id=document.getElementById('UserProfileCity').value;   
            $.ajax({  
                type: "GET",  
                url: "get_city",  
                data: { UserProfilePState : state_id,
                    UserProfilePcity : city_id  },
                success: function(msg){  
                    $("#pcity").html(msg); 
                }  
            });             
            $("#UserProfilePpincode").val($("#UserProfilePcode").val());
            $("#UserProfilePtelephone").val($("#UserProfileTelephone").val());

        }
```

I have to pass the state and city value to another ajax call. and now it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code

## before

`$("#UserProfilePcity").val($("#UserProfileCity").val());`

## after

`$("#UserProfilePcity").val($("body").find('#UserProfileCity').val());`

Comment: Tried but same result as before. @tarikul05

Comment: @ankit it should work,  try deleting cache, another thing your which one is your city id `#city`  or `#UserProfileCity`  ??